# How do I create a persistent virtual folder on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like to map one folder, which unavoidably has brackets in it's path, to another virtual folder that I can use to access it without brackets in the path.

For example:

`C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox (Company Name)\`

would be accessible via something like:

`C:\MyVirtualDropboxFolder\`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### I would like to map one folder to another virtual folder

You can use `mklink` in a `cmd` shell:

```
mklink /d C:\MyVirtualDropboxFolder "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox (Company Name)"
```

Notes:

- The `Target` is quoted as the name contains spaces.
- The above command creates a Directory symbolic link.
- See the table below for other kinds of link you might consider making instead.
- All the links types are persistent (until they are deleted).
- To explicitly delete them see "How to delete" in the last column of the table below.

---

#### mklink

> Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
> ```
>
> Key:
>
> `/D`     Create a Directory symbolic link. (default is file)
>
> `/H`     Create a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
>
> `/J`     Create a Directory Junction.
>
> `Link`   The new symbolic link name.
>
> `Target` The path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.
>
> [image]

Source [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32043/discussion-on-answer-by-davidpostill-how-do-i-create-a-persistent-virtual-folder).